# Set a cookie in Angular if one does not exist

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I want to see if a cookie has been set in Angular, and if it doesn't find a cookie, it will create a new one.

Right now I'm using this:

```
    if ($cookies.get('storedLCookie').length != 0) {
       $cookies.put('storedLCookie','Oatmeal');
    }
```

It doesn't seem to be working, though. Is there another way to test if a cookie is set in Angular?

Answer (score 6):

you can simply do this to check it:

```
var favoriteCookie = $cookies.get('cookieval');

  if ( favoriteCookie ) {
    //exists
  } else {
    //not exists
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The data store in cookie is string or number. When it's a number, you should't judge it by length. Test the following:

```
var a = 3
console.log(a.length) // will return undefined
```

I think you can just write the following instead:

```
if ($cookies.get('storedLCookie')) {
   $cookies.put('storedLCookie','Oatmeal');
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that still didn't work. I did the following and seems to be working:        if ($cookies.get('storedLCookie') == null) {
            $cookies.put('storedLCookie','Oatmeal');
        }

Comment: Then i think the value in youe cookie my store 0, '0' ... . In such case, use null to judge the value is ok.